# SQL server select A.*, count(b) group by

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to run a query on sql server to select all the elements in a table (tableA) with an aggregate from another table

```
select a.*,  count(b.number) from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.id = b.a_id
group by a.id;
```

This gives the following error :

> Error: Column 'a.id' is invalid in the select list because it is not
>   contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> SQLState:  S1000
>   ErrorCode: 8120

What is the right query to get what i want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that

```
select a.*, x.number
from tableA a
inner join
   (select b.a_id, count(b.number) number
   from tableB b
   group by b.a_id) x
on x.a_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*,  
      (Select count(b.number) from tableB b where b.a_id = a.id) as "b count"
   from tableA a;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the query that has group by ,all the columns should appear with an aggregate function or mention in group by list .
Your error is because your  table 'a' column except id ,are not mensioned in group by list and are not appear with an aggregate function.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.*, B.number
from tableA a
inner join
(
a.id a_id,  count(b.number) number from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.id = b.a_id
group by a.id;
) B on B.a_id = a.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Because by using `a.*` you are selecting all the columns from `tableA`. When using aggrgate function `grouby` or anything else you have to mention the column name(s) in group by clause. try this way

```
select a.id,a.name,  count(b.number) from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.id = b.a_id
group by a.id,a.name
```

if you want to select all the columns from `tableA` then you can not use group by.

```
select a.*,  count(b.number) from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.id = b.a_id
```